# When using os.startfile file is not found

Tags: python, windows

```
import os # Tuo os moduuli

print("Valitse suoritettava luokka:"); #Tulosta...
print("1 = Kertolasku");
print("2 = Osamaara");
print("3 = Vertailu");
print("4 = Floydin kolmio");
print("5 = Kertotaulu");
print("6 = Viikonpaiva");
print("7 = Rivit");

v = int(input("Valitse:")) # v = seuraava numero

if v == 1: # jos v on yhtäkuin 1 niin avaa...
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x01.bat')

if v == 2:
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x02.bat')

if v == 3:
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x03.bat')

if v == 4:
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x04.bat')

if v == 5:
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x05.bat')

if v == 21:
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x06.bat') #Secret

if v == 1942: 
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x07.bat') #Secret

if v == 6: 
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x08.bat')

if v == 7: 
os.startfile(r'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH\x09.bat')

else: # muutoin tulosta...
print ("VIRHE - Onko syötetty luku 1-5? Onko JAVA kansio sijainnissa %USERPROFILE%\Desktop ?");
print ("VIRHE - Onko Java asennettu? Onko OS = Windows?");
print ("VIRHE - Onko Java:n path variable asetettu oikein?");

input('Paina ENTER sammuttaaksesi...') #Lisää sulkeva komento.
```

**This code returns the following error:** 
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVJ4H.png)

1. I have checked that file named x01.bat exists in:%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\JAVA\BATCH
2. I have tried to replace \ with / but windows doesn't recognize / as an way to access a directory.
3. I have tried to escape the backslash with another backslash. It only makes the same error with three backslashes instead of 2. (Yes I removed r before ' when I escaped a backslash with a backslash.)
4. I even tried to escape a backslash with a backslash before a backslash but error is the same with more backslashes.

Verdict: It seems that Python 3.6 on Windows 10 wants to add a backslash before a backslash no matter what I do. Because of that windows doesn't know where the .bat file is.

Any help is appreciated, please share your ideas!

Comment: I think the backslashes are correct, because you are using raw strings (`r'...'` syntax). The problem is that `%USERPROFILE%` is not being interpreted. You'll need to do that manually; check out `os.environ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constructing paths in python, it is generally easier to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

So something like

`os.startfile(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop', 'JAVA', 'BATCH', 'x01.bat'))`